# How to tail AJAX to function (event, ui) properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a JQuery range slider which I initialize as follows:

```
$(function sliderRange() {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 1000,
        values: [1, 1000],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val("£" + ui.values[0] + " - £" + ui.values[1]);
                $("#qbr_price_min").val(ui.values[0]);
                $("#qbr_price_max").val(ui.values[1]);
                myAjaxCall();
            }
        });
     $("#amount").val("£" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - £" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
 });
```

So whenever values of the slider were changed I want to make an AJAX call and update my page correspondingly.

The obvious problem is that when user moves the slider it produces to many of input `function (event, ui)` calls. So it ends up with a lot of rudiment AJAX calls, whereas basically I could use only the last one, when slider's movements have stopped.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: "Throttle" or "Debounce" is what you are looking for. You can use a library like lodash

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`lodash.debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#debounce).

It will wait a specified period of time before calling your callback (but will restart the timeout each time you call your callback), invoking only **the last call**.

Your code would look like this with `debounce` in use:

```
var waitTime = 100; // 100ms, adjust the timeout to your needs
var debouncedMyAjaxCall = _.debounce(myAjaxCall, waitTime);

$(function sliderRange() {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 1000,
        values: [1, 1000],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("£" + ui.values[0] + " - £" + ui.values[1]);
            $("#qbr_price_min").val(ui.values[0]);
            $("#qbr_price_max").val(ui.values[1]);
            debouncedMyAjaxCall();
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val("£" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - £" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

call Ajax in stop event :
Refer: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-stop

```
$(function sliderRange() {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 1000,
        values: [1, 1000],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val("£" + ui.values[0] + " - £" + ui.values[1]);
                $("#qbr_price_min").val(ui.values[0]);
                $("#qbr_price_max").val(ui.values[1]);

            },
        stop: function( event, ui ) { myAjaxCall();}
        });
     $("#amount").val("£" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - £" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

> The obvious problem is that when user moves the slider it produces to many of input function (event, ui) calls.

Well observed. But that's two problems, really:

- dialing down the request frequency one way or the other:

  - one way: allow only one request per X milliseconds (a.k.a "throttle")
  - the other way: do one request after the value has not changed for X milliseconds (i.e. has settled down, a.k.a "debouce")
- preventing change to the user interface while a request is running so that the UI and the requests keep in sync

For the purposes here I would say the "debounce" behavior is correct. This is a solved problem, many utility libraries offer functions to do that. For the purpose of the example, let's use [lodash](https://lodash.com).

```
$(function () {
    var slideEventHandler = function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val("£" + ui.values[0] + " - £" + ui.values[1]);
        $("#qbr_price_min").val(ui.values[0]);
        $("#qbr_price_max").val(ui.values[1]);
        ajaxRunning = true;
        $("#slider-range").slider("option", "disabled", true);
        myAjaxCall().always(function () {
            $("#slider-range").slider("option", "disabled", false);
        });
    }

    // debounced handler executes not before 250 ms after the last invocation
    var debouncedHandler = _.debounce(slideEventHandler, 250);

    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 1000,
        values: [1, 1000],
        slide: debouncedHandler
    });

    $("#amount").val("£" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - £" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
```

where `myAjaxCall` should return the Ajax call so we are able to attach additional functionality to it:

```
function myAjaxCall() {
    return $.ajax({ /* ... */ });
}
```

There is a nice article that explains "throttle" and "debounce" in depth, also linked from the lodash documentation: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

There are other ways of dealing with user interface changes while a request is pending than disabling it completely. Think of and implement a better strategy if you want.